# How to extract the slope coefficient from tidy data frame made with Broom Package R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm trying out the tidy methods that Hadley Wickham describes in this video:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rz3_FDVt9eg&t=1902s.  It's straightforward to get certain statistics this way, as long as there is only 1 row in the tidied data frame, but the slope of each linear model is buried in the 2nd row of a tidied data frame made with Broom.  My code is very similar to Hadley's, and looks like this.

```
    library(tidyverse)
    corn_by_county <- corn_final_long %>% group_by(County) %>% nest()
    
    # define & run linear models for each county
    corn_county <- function(df){
      lm(Yield ~ Year, data = df)}
    
    corn_models <- corn_by_county %>% mutate(model = map(data, corn_county))
    corn_output <- corn_models %>% mutate(tidy = map(model, broom::tidy),
                                          glance = map(model, broom::glance),
                                          augment = map(model, broom::augment),
                                          rsq = glance %>% map_dbl('r.squared'),
                                          slope = tidy %>% map_dbl('estimate')) ## slope not working
```

The "slope" is on the 2nd row of the nested 'tidy' data frame inside the "tidy" column of "corn_output".  I've tried this code

```
slope = tidy %>% filter(term == 'Year') %>% map_dbl('estimate')
```

However, that is not working.  How do I extract the slope?  Thank you.

Here is a sample of my data.

```
corn_final_long <- structure(list(Year = c(1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L), County = c("Aurora", "Beadle", "Bennett", 
"Bon Homme", "Brookings", "Brown", "Brule", "Buffalo", "Butte", 
"Campbell", "Charles Mix", "Clark", "Clay", "Codington", "Corson", 
"Custer", "Davison", "Day", "Deuel", "Dewey", "Douglas", "Edmunds", 
"Fall River", "Faulk", "Grant", "Gregory", "Haakon", "Hamlin", 
"Hand", "Hanson", "Harding", "Hughes", "Hutchinson", "Hyde", 
"Jackson", "Jerauld", "Jones", "Kingsbury", "Lake", "Lawrence", 
"Lincoln", "Lyman", "Marshall", "Mccook", "Mcpherson", "Meade", 
"Mellette", "Miner", "Minnehaha", "Moody", "Oglala Lakota", "Pennington", 
"Perkins", "Potter", "Roberts", "Sanborn", "Spink", "Stanley", 
"Sully", "Todd", "Tripp", "Turner", "Union", "Walworth", "Yankton", 
"Ziebach", "Aurora", "Beadle", "Bennett", "Bon Homme", "Brookings", 
"Brown", "Brule", "Buffalo", "Butte", "Campbell", "Charles Mix", 
"Clark", "Clay", "Codington", "Corson", "Custer", "Davison", 
"Day", "Deuel", "Dewey", "Douglas", "Edmunds", "Fall River", 
"Faulk", "Grant", "Gregory", "Haakon", "Hamlin", "Hand", "Hanson", 
"Harding", "Hughes", "Hutchinson", "Hyde"), Yield = c(47.3, 58.9, 
103.8, 71.4, 71.7, 65.3, 53.9, 72.8, 84.8, 61, 59, 63.4, 92.4, 
75.2, 41, 94.4, 62.7, 63.6, 74, 47.7, 57.7, 51.5, 102.1, 57.6, 
72.4, 58, 39.1, 68.2, 68.6, 66, 73.3, 85, 78.8, 52.7, 45, 40.9, 
76.7, 63.6, 80.6, 85, 96.3, 87, 65.8, 74.2, 55.9, 78.8, 47.8, 
66.2, 92.6, 93.1, 60, 62.9, 53.5, 60.2, 70.5, 64.8, 68.9, 60, 
59, 94.8, 42.2, 89.5, 105.1, 68.4, 78.9, 45, 25.4, 35.8, 43.5, 
27.3, 63.2, 46, 32.3, NA, 83.3, 80.8, 34.2, 53.8, 68.1, 66.2, 
16, 100, 26.3, 44.5, 70.6, 16.7, 27.2, 29.2, 93.7, 33.5, 64.4, 
30.9, 30, 60.1, 30.7, 34.5, NA, 41.1, 38.9, 28.2)), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just pick the 2nd element of the "estimate" column of the `broom` output:

```
corn_output <- corn_models %>% 
               mutate(tidy = map(model, broom::tidy),
                      glance = map(model, broom::glance),
                      augment = map(model, broom::augment),
                      rsq = glance %>% map_dbl('r.squared'),
                      slope = tidy %>% map_dbl(function(x) x$estimate[2]))
```

Answer (score 1):

And just for reference an approach using `filter` and `pull` to get the slope:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

corn_by_county <- corn_final_long %>% group_by(County) %>% nest()

# define & run linear models for each county
corn_county <- function(df){
  lm(Yield ~ Year, data = df)}

corn_models <- corn_by_county %>% mutate(model = map(data, corn_county))
corn_output <- corn_models %>% mutate(tidy = map(model, broom::tidy),
                                      glance = map(model, broom::glance),
                                      augment = map(model, broom::augment),
                                      rsq = glance %>% map_dbl('r.squared'),
                                      slope = tidy %>% map_dbl(~ filter(.x, term == "Year") %>% pull(estimate))) ## slope not working

head(corn_output)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 8
#> # Groups:   County [6]
#>   County   data         model tidy        glance       augment        rsq  slope
#>   <chr>    <list>       <lis> <list>      <list>       <list>       <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 Aurora   <tibble [2 ~ <lm>  <tibble [2~ <tibble [1 ~ <tibble [2 ~     1 -21.9 
#> 2 Beadle   <tibble [2 ~ <lm>  <tibble [2~ <tibble [1 ~ <tibble [2 ~     1 -23.1 
#> 3 Bennett  <tibble [2 ~ <lm>  <tibble [2~ <tibble [1 ~ <tibble [2 ~     1 -60.3 
#> 4 Bon Hom~ <tibble [2 ~ <lm>  <tibble [2~ <tibble [1 ~ <tibble [2 ~     1 -44.1 
#> 5 Brookin~ <tibble [2 ~ <lm>  <tibble [2~ <tibble [1 ~ <tibble [2 ~     1  -8.50
#> 6 Brown    <tibble [2 ~ <lm>  <tibble [2~ <tibble [1 ~ <tibble [2 ~     1 -19.3
```